# Where is php.ini in php v.5.4.6?

Tags: php

This file seems is missing at all. I see only a two files `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`, but both of them is not a configuration of current php. What I need to do if I want to add a mysqli extension in php, where I can do it?

OS Windows 7.

**Solution**

Rename `php.ini-production` to `php.ini` and uncomment `extension_dir` by removing `;`. That is all.

Comment: Quick question php.ini-production is present in source code but not in installation directory. Where did you copied this file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It all depends on your `Operating System`

Create a file `check.php`, and it will show your where `php.ini` is.

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: check `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: `Loaded Configuration File` - NONE.

Comment: Then you have no `php.ini` loaded. You may have deleted it. How did you installed PHP?

Comment: Rename or copy one of `php.ini-development` or `php.ini-production` to `php.ini`, one is for development and one for production (live). The development one will show you errors and help you debug your scripts.

Comment: Actually, it's the first what I have done, but than I have `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Well, not of both, but yes, php.ini-production to php.ini is working. But I still can't mind why mysqli extension is missing, I'm uncommented it, but in phpinfo() nothing about it.

Comment: In `phpinfo()` it's says that you have loaded `php.ini` ? Did you restarted apache?

Comment: Yes, all is great now, it was because in php.ini directive extension_dir was under commment. I removed `;` and **Thank you folk!**

Comment: This answer is invalid now. Because since 5.4.* version php.ini is not loaded by default. If you look at phpinfo() you will see php.ini location as php-install-location/lib but its not there. You can find the solution provided in the question itself.

Comment: @UmakantPatil you should downvote all questions that you think are deprecated. This is 1 year old.

Answer (score -1):

The location of **php.ini** is `/etc/php.ini` in Linux.